# Looking for the manufacturer of this IC (Identification required by logo)

Tags: identification

I have several different ICs laying around with the same manufacturer icon marked on top of the ICs. I searched on several IC-logo web sites, but so far, I couldn't identify the manufacturer.

Do you know who is the manufacturer of this IC?[image: IC]

Thank you
!

Comment: You generally don't need to identify the specific manufacturer unless you are operating at some limit of specification. See the [TI LM393](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf) datasheet instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably manufactured by [Beijing Estek Electronics](http://www.estek.com.cn/en/), here's the [datasheet](http://www.estek.com.cn/UploadFile/Download/201512081533450550.pdf).

Next time, if you look for component manufacturer, go to site like datasheetarchive.com, and put component name in the search. It will list all datasheets available for the component, and if there's no logo displayed which you will match, you can guess from supplier's name, or just open PDFs until you find document with logo needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did this on Octopart and Alldatasheet, but not on datasheetarchive. Thanks for the links!